# Como mudar valor de variavel depois que o usuario enviar um formulario?

Tags: php, formulário, post, if, else

Esse código abaixo vai imprimir `<i class="far fa-star"></i>` se o `rowCount == 0` e se for `> 0` vai imprimir `<i class="fas fa-check"></i>`, depois que o usuario envia o formulario eles não poderam ver o `<i class="fas fa-check"></i>` ao menos que ele atualize a página, depois que o usuario envia o formulario a página atualiza sozinha, mas ele precisa atualizar a página mais uma vez para poder ver o `<i class="fas fa-check"></i>`:

```
if ($rowCountFav == 0) {
  $favIcon = '<i class="far fa-star"></i>';
}else{$favIcon = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  if(isset($_POST["fav"])){ 
    if ($rowCountFav == 0) {
      $favorito = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `favorito` (user_id, nameItem) VALUES (:user_id, :nameItem)");
      $favorito->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $favorito->bindParam(':nameItem', $nameItem, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $favorito->execute();
    }
  } 
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <button class="btnSub btnA" type="submit" name="fav" />
    Favorito <?= $favIcon;?>
  </button> <span class="ml-1 mr-2">-</span> 
</form>
```

**O que eu quero**: Eu quero que imprima o `<i class="fas fa-check"></i>` depois que o usuario enviar o formulario.

> EDITADO, SUGESTÃO DE RiscadoOoOoO e RabisCadoO

PRECISO QUE ESSE `<i class="fas fa-check"></i>` SEJA EXIBIDO DENTRO DO FORMULARIO APÓS O SUBMIT.

> FINAL DA EDIÇAO.

Então eu tentei isso, mas nada mudou:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  if(isset($_POST["fav"])){ 
    if ($rowCountFav == 0) {
      $favorito = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `favorito` (user_id, nameItem) VALUES (:user_id, :nameItem)");
      $favorito->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $favorito->bindParam(':nameItem', $nameItem, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $favorito->execute();
    }else{$favIcon = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';} ## eu apenas add essa linha ##
  } 
}
```

Alguem pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução foi declarar o valor do $rowCount depois da query de `INSERT`, agora o icone é trocado logo depois que o usuario enviar o formulario, e não precisa atualizar a página.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  if(isset($_POST["fav"])){ 
    if ($rowCountFav == 0) {
      $favorito = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `favorito` (user_id, nameItem) VALUES (:user_id, :nameItem)");
      $favorito->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $favorito->bindParam(':nameItem', $nameItem, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $favorito->execute();
      $rowCountFav = 1;
    }
  } 
}

if ($rowCountFav == 0) {
  $favIcon = '<i class="far fa-star"></i>';
} else {
  $favIcon = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
}

?>
<form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <button class="btnSub btnA" type="submit" name="fav" />
    Favorito <?= $favIcon;?>
  </button> <span class="ml-1 mr-2">-</span> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Natalie, tente assim:

```
form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <button class="btnSub btnA" type="submit" name="fav" />
    Favorito <?= if(isset($favIcon)){echo $favIcon;}?>
  </button> <span class="ml-1 mr-2">-</span> 
</form>
```

Se der certo, avise a gente, por favor ;)